# How to exposing Spinnaker to End Users without tunnling

Tags: spinnaker

```
How to Access Spinnaker by using Security with out tunnling
```

How to Access Spinnaker by using Security without tunnling spinnaker, expose open world.in secure way! exposing Spinnaker to End Users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

```
echo "host: 0.0.0.0" | tee \
    ~/.hal/default/service-settings/gate.yml \
    ~/.hal/default/service-settings/deck.yml
```

```
sudo hal deploy apply
```

Comment: And for security use SSO or SAML intergrations

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're running in Kubernetes, but pretty similar for other platforms as well - https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/quickstart/halyard-gke-public/